# Nginx - HTTPS SSL Issue with Certbot

Tags: nginx, networking, ssl, https

I've setup HTTPS SSL with letsencrypt and certbot and the main domain was pointing to the the machine that is running my site, working fine etc. Until of course I tried setting up the SSL for HTTPS.

Certbot did what it's supposed to, I just can't get access to that site anymore, I've looked at Cloudflare and seen people say to use Full or Full (strict) however I'm not sure if these work just yet due to them taking some before they switch etc.

However, I'm also having a problem with a reverse proxy, I've installed [Plankanban](https://github.com/plankanban/planka) on a Raspberry Pi hosted on port 8889, I'm trying to run this through the reverse proxy but everything I've tried just isn't working, I'm wanting it to be accessible from "plankanban.domainname.com" and not "plankanban.domainname.com:8889" otherwise there's no point in having the subdomain really may as well just use the domain name with the port which isn't nice looking in my opinion.

I'm running my Nginx blocks through the conf.d directory within Nginx due to manually installing. Below I will show my webserver with SSL that isn't working.

```
server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        server_name  domainname.com www.domainname.com;
    
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    
        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/domainname;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    
        #error_page  404              /404.html;
        #location = /404.html {
        #    root   /usr/share/nginx/domainname;
        #}
    
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #    root   /usr/share/nginx/domainname;
        #}
    
        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}
    
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}
    
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }
    server {
        if ($host = www.domainname.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
        if ($host = domainname.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
    
        server_name  domainname.com www.domainname.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
```

And here is my reverse proxy (which is disabled to try fixing the main site):

```
#server {
#    listen 80 default_server;
#    listen [::]:80 default_server;
#    listen 443 default_server;
#    listen [::]:443 default_server;

#    server_name plankanban.domainname.xyz;
    #proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
#    location / {
#            proxy_pass http://localhost:8889/;
            #proxy_redirect off;
#            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
#            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
#            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#    }
#}
```

Where is the best to read into getting into this stuff? Just Networking in general, I'd love to be able to actually figure it out and understand it but I always wonder where people actually start. Any guides and or courses that may be of any use regarding this at all?

Thanks in advance,
~Blood